# how to keep the code running after log in (python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am trying to write a programe that lets the user create a log in and then it runs a menu system. the problem i have is it keeps looping the log in code instead of moving onto the next part which is the menu bit. i have tried adding break commands but this seemed to stop after the log in  but not run the next part.

```
# Aaron Dyer Software Engineering Fundamentals Data Base## #
# A Prompt asking the user to log in#
print("Please enter log in details")
# The below code will allow the user to create a username and password and log in"
def add_new_user():
    username = input("Enter your username: ")
    password = input("Enter your password: ")
    user_type = input("Enter your user type (admin, inventory-checker): ")
    with open("userdata.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write("%s %s %s\n" % (username, password, user_type))

def user_authentication():
    username = input("Enter your username: ")
    password = input("Enter your password: ")
    with open("userdata.txt", "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            user_data = line.split()
            if user_data[0] == username and user_data[1] == password:
                print("Login successful!")
                return user_data[2]
    print("Incorrect password or username.")
    return None

def main():
    add_new_user()
    while True:
        user_type = user_authentication()
        if user_type is None:
            continue
        if user_type == "admin":
            print("You are logged in as an admin.")
            continue
        elif user_type == "inventory-checker":
            continue
            print("You are logged in as an inventory checker.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
#Below is the menu stystem to access the detials about the laptops and iphone's#
def menu():
    print("[1] Laptops")
    print("[2] iPhones")
    option = input("Choose your device: ")
    if option == "1":
        print("[1] S5750")
        print("[2] S5577")
        print("[3] S5563")
        print("[4] S5744")
        print("[5] S5765")
        print("[6] S5944")
        print("[7] S5507")
        print("[8] S5509")
        laptop_option = input("Choose your laptop: ")
        # do something based on the chosen laptop
    elif option == "2":
        # add options for iPhones here
        pass
    else:
        print("Invalid choice. Please try again.")
```

Comment: Your `while True` loop has no exit condition. The function never `return`s nor `break`s the loop. "i have tried adding break commands" where have you tried them, and what was the result? Please update your code to include that detail

Answer (score 1):

You just need to put the menu function before main .
and just go to menu function after check that is admin or inventory checker .

[worked program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEfPJ.png)

that is your code after editing :

```
# Aaron Dyer Software Engineering Fundamentals Data Base## #
# A Prompt asking the user to log in#
print("Please enter log in details")
# The below code will allow the user to create a username and password and log in"
def add_new_user():
    username = input("Enter your username: ")
    password = input("Enter your password: ")
    user_type = input("Enter your user type (admin, inventory-checker): ")
    with open("userdata.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write("%s %s %s\n" % (username, password, user_type))

def user_authentication():
    username = input("Enter your username: ")
    password = input("Enter your password: ")
    with open("userdata.txt", "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            user_data = line.split()
            if user_data[0] == username and user_data[1] == password:
                print("Login successful!")
                return user_data[2]
    print("Incorrect password or username.")
    return None

def menu():
    print("[1] Laptops")
    print("[2] iPhones")
    option = input("Choose your device: ")
    if option == "1":
        print("[1] S5750")
        print("[2] S5577")
        print("[3] S5563")
        print("[4] S5744")
        print("[5] S5765")
        print("[6] S5944")
        print("[7] S5507")
        print("[8] S5509")
        laptop_option = input("Choose your laptop: ")
        # do something based on the chosen laptop
    elif option == "2":
        # add options for iPhones here
        pass
    else:
        print("Invalid choice. Please try again.")

def main():
    add_new_user()
    while True:
        user_type = user_authentication()
        if user_type is None:
            continue
        if user_type == "admin":
            print("You are logged in as an admin.")
            menu()
            continue
        elif user_type == "inventory-checker":
            menu()
            print("You are logged in as an inventory checker.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
#Below is the menu stystem to access the detials about the laptops and iphone's#
```